# Postgresql SELECT performance and optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with 14_000 rows. Not to many. My query

```
SELECT "wells".* FROM "wells" WHERE (LOWER(name) LIKE '%abc%' OR code LIKE '%ABC%')
  ORDER BY "wells"."name_nso" ASC, "wells"."extra_name" ASC
  LIMIT 10;
```

takes "Execution Time: 2.701 ms"

For this table i have two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX wells_btree_idx_on_name_nso
ON public.wells USING btree
(name_nso COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX wells_gin_idx_on_name_lower
ON public.wells USING gin
(lower(name) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

If i remove LIMIT 10, it takes "Execution Time: 0.894 ms".  4 times faster.

Is it worth looking into how to speed up a query with LIMIT 10 to those 0.894 ms, or are those 2.701 ms fast enough and not worth bothering with?

Comment: Doing fuzzy string matches are always going to be slower than exact matches. There lots of things that you could do - e.g. if you have predefined groups you can build materialized views with them and query for the exact matches.
At the end of the day the answer is - it always depends. Do you run the query once? Or thousands of times? If it is run rarely, you could wait. If not -> you better sharpen your DB skills :D

Comment: Only you can decide if 2.7ms is "fast enough".

Comment: The query is executed rarely. But if something can be executed faster, why not make it faster. Thx

Comment: Is this another example of our ability to measure extremely short time intervals combined with a total complete inability to interpolate that time in human terms? Will anyone ever notice that the process took .0027 seconds vs. .00089 seconds? Yes the 1st is 3-4 times longer, but even it is beyond perception.

Comment: Hi @sssebaaa text search is always slow rather than integer. Create another index or create a composite index where code column exists. By default order by clause works in ascending order so no need to type ASC in order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

PostGreSQL is the slowest RDBMS when running LIKE operator with a insensitive case collation. You need to use LOWER or UPPER because with ICU collation there is a bug...
Read :
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACykOPQKHGRLzuAB1Mvn9Pizatp9g%3DJG_CHYxn4VOD%2BD7E4Vcg%40mail.gmail.com

You can use citext type to do so...

Your indexes won't be usefull pour the LIKE with two %...